# How to remove element with empty attr on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using attr in jquery to add different photos into an overlay depending on which image is clicked which works well. But if there is no image inserted I want to remove the `containerImage img`. This is the closest I have gotten to click and remove empty tags but I want it to happen on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $("#containerImage img");

    $container.click(function(){
        if ($container.attr("src")==="") {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            console.log("not empty");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the html, in the img tag I am calling the images to go into the empty src

```
  <img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail"></img>
  <img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail"></img>
  <img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail"></img>

  <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="boxImage w2" project="Project Title"   
 description="description"   images="images/4.jpg, images/5.jpg"></img>
```

So in the above example there are only 2 images, leaving me with a 3rd empty box and I want to remove that box after the images have filled in.

Here is the code that is filling in the images, as well as the titles and descriptions

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxImage').click(function () {
        var project = $(this).attr('project'),
        description = $(this).attr('description'),
        images = $(this).attr('images');

        $(".projectsTitle").text(project);
        $(".projectsDescription").text(description);


        var imageArray = images.split(',');
        dataloaded(imageArray);
    });

    function dataloaded(array) {
        // clear existing images
        var $thumbnails = $('.galleryThumbnail');
        $thumbnails.attr('src', '');

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $('.galleryThumbnail:eq(' + i + ')').attr('src', array[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `$container.click();`?

Comment: where's the code that inserts the images? Should be checking there really

Comment: You appear to be making up HTML tag attributes (project, description, images). You should preface these attribute names with `data-`.

Comment: Also, `images` is an invalid attribute. Use `data-*` attribute like: `data-images` instead. Same goes for `project`, `description` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$thumbnails.filter("[src='']").remove();`

First, note that:

`</img>` is an invalid closing tag for `<img>`  (IMG is a self-closing tag)
`image`, `description`, and `project` are invalid HTML attributes. (Use `data-*` attributes)

```
<img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail">
<img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail">
<img src="" class="boxed galleryThumbnail">

<img src="images/image1.jpg" class="boxImage w2" data-project="Project Title" data-description="description" data-images="images/4.jpg,images/5.jpg">
```

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand

    $('.boxImage').click(function () {
        var data = $(this).data();
        $(".projectsTitle").text(data.project);
        $(".projectsDescription").text(data.description);
        dataloaded( data.images.split(',') );
    });

    function dataloaded(array) {
        var $thumbnails = $('.galleryThumbnail');
        $thumbnails.attr('src', '');
        for (var i=0; i<$thumbnails.length; i++) {
          $('.galleryThumbnail:eq(' + i + ')').attr('src', array[i]);
        }
        $thumbnails.filter("[src='']").remove();
    }

});
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/mehupe/5/edit)**

Now that this is done what I don't understand is... if you remove your images that don't have any `src` attribute **on dom ready**, your script falls to fill any image cause ... well, it's removed.

Comment: well I want them removed after the images get filled from the first time, which those are loading fine as of now its just the following empty boxes that I want to be removed

Comment: Ok, so you have more primary thumbnails, right? Clicking on one of them you want to show more info about that item by filling some empty images and extracting the data content, right? If you remove your thumbnails... and if one clicks on another *project main thumbnail* ... you'll have no images to fill cause ... they **are removed!** Makes sense?

Comment: adding the  $thumbnails.filter("[src='']").remove(); worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: @EmyleeEsteban if that's the case what you're trying to achieve will not work http://jsbin.com/mehupe/6/edit The second main thumbnail has 3 images in array, but after you click "ONE", "TWO" will show only 2 images. So if that's what you're trying to build it's wrong. I might suggest another way... and **that simply not to have any thumbnails on page load. Click on an image will create them (after removing existent ones)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#containerImage img').each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(this).attr("src") === "") {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            console.log("not empty");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question was confusingly written so I've edited it with what I believe you meant. Here is what I would suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $("#containerImage img");

    $container.click(function(){
        if (!$(this).attr("src")) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            console.log("not empty");
        }
    });

    $container.click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmKvq/

Fade out demo to show it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmKvq/1/

In other words, just call the event handlers.

Here is another approach, in case you're allergic to calling the click handler en masse:

```
$container
    .filter(function(){return !this.getAttribute('src')})
    .fadeOut(
        1000,
        function(){$(this).remove();}
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmKvq/3/

Comment: Both the above answers clear out all the images not just the empty ones

Comment: That's because there were some other flaws I didn't notice. See my edit.

Comment: still clearing out all the images, or is there a way to run that after my code that is inserting images?

Comment: Well, um, put the call to the `$container.click()` *after* you insert the images... So I would say yes? Note that I didn't just add the `$container.click()` part, I also had to fix the click handler itself (as it was wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Following assumes there is only one image

Several approaches are to trigger the click event after attaching the event handler:

```
$container.click(function(){
    if ($container.attr("src")==="") {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        console.log("not empty");
    }
}).click();/* triiger a click event*/
```

Or wrap the handler into a function that can be used for both click handling or called by iteself

```
function checkImage(){
     if ($container.attr("src")==="") {
            $container.remove();
        } else {
            console.log("not empty");
        }
}

/* use as handler */
$('#containerImage img').click(checkImage);

/* call function when page loads*/
checkImage();
```

Comment: I missed it as well, but there's some basic flaws in the OPs click handler. Also note the second example isn't really the same as calling the event handler on an element, so it's probably not really right.

Comment: @JaredFarrish right...OP said it was working which it won't when have more than one image